# How can i use multiple wherelessthan in firebase?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
   db.collection("Recipe")
            .whereLessThan("Kcal",morning_kcal)
            .whereLessThan("calbohydrate",morning_carbohyrate)
            .whereLessThan("protein", morning_protein)
            .whereLessThan("fat", morning_fat)
            .get()
```

I want to get recipe data from firebase firestore.
when user add their data on app  the app get recipe data from firestore
using mornig-Kcal,protein,fat,carbohydrate which is  calcucated on app.

for that I tried to use wherelessthan 4 times. but android studio says I can use it only one time.
there are many recipe data on my firestore so I can't use wherequalTo.

How can I make my app  work  as I expected?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to perform a query that's not supported by Firestore.  You can only use one field in a range filter per query, as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

If you need a range filter on multiple fields, you will have to use only one for the query, then filter the rest in your client code.